# ROOT CAUSE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space [Using Apache for Coldfusion 7 on localhost]

Tags: apache, coldfusion

I am getting following error message all of the sudden. 5 minuted before everything was working fine.

```
500

ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space


javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Please help to correct this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried increasing the Java VM maximum memory allocation ? e.g.

```
java -Xmx512m ...
```

will set the maximum memory allocation to 512m. You may be running with the default memory settings, and that may not be sufficient for your application. See [here](http://helpdesk.postmaster.co.in/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=13&nav=0,4) for an introduction to the available options and what they mean.

Comment: Might also just be a bug that causes the endless allocation of memory.

Comment: Very true. I'd assumed a) that the app worked normally and b) a lack of familiarity re. the memory model. Those assumptions may not be correct :-)